# Screen gets white while scrolling up and down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, particles.js

following is a URL I am developing `www.vidyotan.org`. The site works fine on desktop but when opened in a mobile phone in chrome browser if you see scrolling it bottom and up quickly you can see that it's lagging it firstly displays a white background then it displays all the content which is a very buggy thing. I am trying to solve this error for a very long time. Please, can someone help me out?

I am using particle.js

```
<style>
#particles-js
    {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100% !important;
      position: fixed !important;
      top: inherit;
      bottom: 0;
    }
</style>
```

after implementing particles.js this buggy thing occurs. Can anyone provide a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would have posted this as a comment but i cant..

the website is showing fine on my phone. probably your phone ram is low or you have opened so many applications. These often cause lagging

Comment: I cleared all ram and closed the unwanted applications worked perfect :)